# Animate a UITableViewCell Out of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation

Is it possible to animate a `UITableViewCell` so that when it is selected, it appears to come out of its table, shrink, and appear to disappear into a button on the Navigation Bar?

I feel like this is doable, but I am not sure where to begin.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the space where the cell was before it comes out of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your view controller is in a `UINavigationController` it's possible using `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

1. Set your view controller to be the delegate of your navigation controller (`self.navigationcontroller.delegate = self`)
2. Implement the method `-navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` and return an object that conforms to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol.
3. Implement the methods for that protocol. In the method `-animateTransition:` you will be passed a parameter that conforms to `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`. This object will allow you to get a reference to the view controller you're transitioning to & from.
4. In the same method, you're going to do the animation. It's going to be custom. You will want to take a snapshot of the view you're transitioning to. At this point it's a matter of figuring out the cell's location, creating a view that contains an image of the cell, and performing the necessary animations and transforms.

As with most custom animations, this isn't a trivial thing but this should get you going down the right path. Hope this helps.